# Removing/parsing rows from a matrix in R

Tags: r, rows

I'm trying to parse out specific rows from a data matrix. The actual data is numeric and comprises a single column. I've used this method before for other data, and I cannot figure out why this isn't working.

```
csize = data.matrix(wc$Csize)
length(csize)
[1] 134
csize[-111,][-110,][-107,][-105,][-104,][-94,][-88,][-68,][-58,][-57,][-56,][-30,][-22,][,1]
Error in csize[-111, ][-110, ] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

Here is the code that does work for me with other data:

```
w.pc.res <- prcomp(sizeshapew)                  
w.pcdata <- w.pc.res$x
length(w.pcdata)
[1] 11792
w.pcdata[-111,][-110,][-107,][-105,][-104,][-94,][-88,][-68,][-58,][-57,][-56,][-30,][-22,][,1]
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it likes the multiple subscripting, just provide the subscripts in a vector e.g csize[c(-111, -110, ...),]